# How to plot .txt file

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with two columns, called Fx1. In column 1 it shows deflection calculations and in column 2 it shows force calculation (about 100).

I loaded the text file into matlab as a variable, called Fx1.

How do I plot this text file as a graph, with deflection as my x value, and force as my y value? Apparently, I am supposed to define my variables, but I do not know how to do so when I'm getting the data from a .txt file.

This is what I did and I did not get the correct graph:

```
plot(fx1)
```

Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of my text file:
[Here is my text file. It continues for many values, I just copy and pasted the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctYT6.png)

Here is a screenshot of my whole workspace, I am trying to  make a plot for all txt files between Fx1-Fx9.

[Matlab work space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXwhI.png)

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help if you don't provide. 1) A more detailed description of the file format, preferably an example file. 2) The code you are using to use to load and plot the data.

Comment: Sorry! Please take another look if you can, I updated the info.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate fx1 into two vector. Use these commands:

```
    x=fx1(:,2)';
    y=fx1(:,1)';
    plot(x,y);
```

In additional you can combine these three command to one command:

```
    plot(fx1(:,2)',fx1(:,1)');
```

Comment: It tells me "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" when I run it. Do you know how to troubleshoot that? In my work space, the variable Fx1 has a value of "185045 x 1 double", if that helps you at all.

Comment: So you load data bad. Probably you have only one raw data.

Comment: Take a look at my question now, it is a picture of my text file!

Comment: I use this command and it load data correctly: ** load('d:\a.txt'); **

Comment: Could you look at my question again, I updated the question to give me more insight.

Comment: Oh. To use plot command, two vector must be in the same dimensional.

Comment: I think the issue is how I'm loading my Fx1 file. My Fx1.txt file is a two column text file. How do i import two column text file so it shows up in as two columns?